# Redis cluster ensure some keys reside on physically different instances

Tags: redis

I have N redis instances running in redis cluster and there is a requirement to *never* place keys with different hashtag prefixes on the same physical instance

So, there are N instances and M prefixes where M <= N

For example, we can have

```
instance 1
{alpha/1}super key
{alpha/2}super key
instance 2
{beta/1}super key
```

but we can't have

```
instance 1
{alpha/1}super key
{beta/1}super key
instance 2
{alpha/2}super key
```

i.e. in the 2nd case `beta*` resides on the same instance as `alpha*` which is not allowed

What would be the most straightforward way to achieve the desired result?

The use case for this is to properly distribute load and exclude logic working with `alpha*` to influence performance of logic working with `beta*`

All logic resides within lua scripts, `alpha*` is always heavy loaded and resource hungry, while `beta*` is much-much easier to handle but has strict latency requirements

I know I could put `beta*` to a dedicated instance or even move it out of the cluster, but if there is some obvious way to implement it within a single cluster would be really nice

Comment: Assuming you are referring to v3's cluster, why not just use static hash tags and configure the ranges:nodes per your liking? (I would, however, use two separate and independent clustered databases instead - divide and conquer ;)).

Comment: `cluster keyslot` and `cluster addslots` seemed to do the magic! Thanks @ItamarHaber

Comment: Exactly. Also, the http://redis.io/commands/cluster-setslot command can be useful.